# Error running sample "Twilio Video React App". getting error - Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Priority'. TS2345

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I was trying to run the sample Twilio Video React App taken from https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react
I have installed npm and all dependencies required for the project. When I do npm start I get the error -

> Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
>
> > Failed to compile. I:/Project/twilio-video-app-react-master/src/components/VideoTrack/VideoTrack.tsx
> > TypeScript error in I:/Project/twilio-video-app-react-master/src/components/VideoTrack/VideoTrack.tsx(36,27):
> > Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Priority'.  TS2345

```
if (track.setPriority && priority) {
    // Passing `null` to setPriority will set the track's priority to that which it was published with.
    track.setPriority(null);                        
    }
```

But when I look at the documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-track-priority-api, I see they use setPriority(null).

Is there anything I am missing. I have not done any changes to the sample yet!